# Question about else statement following if-else

Tags: c#

I'm brushing up on some C# and had a question that seemed dumb. In C# (and probably most languages), can you put an else statement inside an if-else statement?

e.g.

```
if (clause) {
  execute code
}
else if (clause) {
  execute code
     else {
       execute code
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, just try it and see if it works!

Comment: Have you tried? If you did the compiler would tell you it's not possible

Comment: How would you even expect that to work? When should that `else` block, that has no corresponding `if`, be executed?

Comment: The documentation for [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#the-if-statement) seems pretty clear - the `else` must connect to an `if`.

Comment: @UnholySheep The program would look at the if statement, test it, if false then move to the else if, but wouldn't test the else because the else is inside of the else if which would have to be true for it to test... thanks haha rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be erroneous.
You probably want something like this instead:

```cs
if (clause)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    if (anotherClause)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I assume you are new to programming, so I can talk a little bit about if else statements.

`else` does not make any sense when you don't have an `if` before it.

For example,
This statement makes sense:

```
IF you are 21 or older, you can drink. ELSE, you cannot drink.
```

While this does not:

```
ELSE, you cannot drink
```

Hopefully my answer helps

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible but you can do something like that instead :

```
if(condition)
{
  //code that get executed after cheking the condition 
}
else if(another condition)
{
  // code that get executed after checking the second condition
}
else
{
 // code get executed if the first and the second condition are not true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That code wouldn't work because you need an `if` for there to be an `else`. If you want to do an additional check for something within the `else if`, you need to add an `if` first, like this:

```
if (clause)
{
  execute code
}
else if (clause)
{
  execute code
    if (clause)
    {
       execute code
    } 
    else
    {
       execute code
    }
}
```